# How to simulate ICMP messages

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, pcap, libpcap, icmp

I would like to know whether there are any programs which will help me to generate ICMP messages. I have a target board running with linux for arm and all of the ICMP messages need to be tested against it.

These all are the messages need to be tested:

- 3 Destination Unreachable
- 12    Parameter Problem
- 11    Time exceeded
- 4 Source Quench
- 30    Trace route
- 5 Re-direct

I shall take the trace of these communications in wireshark as well.

Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). This is a comfortable packet generator written in python. You can integrate it into your python scripts.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the information.Currently I'm trying it out with NMAP and SING.I'm able to simulate all the ICMP messages using both NPING and SING but the actual requirement is to get the parameter problem response from the host machine.I guess i will have to deliberately send a scrambled/corrupt TCP request to host and in turn it will respond with parameter problem response.Any idea how to simulate a scrambled/corrupt message to host?

Comment: Again: Use scapy. You can really send _any_ packet you like, no matter how broken.

Comment: I'm on it Master.Will update you the results back.Thanks again.

Comment: Scapy might be a bit of an overkill for generating and sending a few malformed packets. You might want to try Ostinato (https://code.google.com/p/ostinato/)

Comment: Thanks Countermode and Malt.Actually i was able to generate the message using Ostinato. Quiet a simple and straight forward tool to use.